# install php7.0-pgsql - Unable to locate package php-pgsql

Tags: php, debian, apt-get, apt, php-pgsql

I am trying to install php7.0-pgsql, but always get

E: Unable to locate package phpXXX-pgsql

I am trying

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install php7.0-pgsql=7.0.12-1+deb
```

or

```
apt-get install php7.0-pgsql=7.0.12-1
```

or

```
apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

or even

```
apt-get install php-pgsql
```

always with the same result. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: answering own question above, if someone needs it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y php7.0-pgsql
```

Comment: You can view the revision history of a post by clicking the "edited" text below the post.

Comment: I got "Permission denied" while trying to edit sources.list file, so I had to run `sudo -s` to switch to root user on the shell.

Comment: I got this `Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration detail`